# Any example of matrix operations with JavaCV?

Tags: arrays, opencv, matrix, javacv

I need to convert an image into an matrix to do math with it, like what is done with Matlab (`imadd`, `imsubtract`, `immultiply`, `imdivide`).

I only managed to do this:

```
CvMat mtx = new CvMat(iplUltima);
opencv_core.cvTranspose(mtx,mtx);

iplUltima = new IplImage(mtx);        
pbxImagenTransformada.setIcon(new ImageIcon(iplUltima.getBufferedImage()));
```

but when I try to do the same with `cvSum` or `cvAdd` I got errors. Can you give me an example of use? I tried to replace `cvTranspose` by `cvAdd` but it is an error.

Comment: For example, in this case: 
###code###
CvMat mtx = new CvMat(iplUltima);
opencv_core.cvDet(mtx);
iplUltima = new IplImage(mtx);        
pbxImagenTransformada.setIcon(new ImageIcon(iplUltima.getBufferedImage()));

###code###
I get this error when I click in the bottom: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (mat.rows == mat.cols && (type == CV_32F || type == CV_64F)) in determinant, file /home/gaby/Desktop/OpenCV-2.4.0/modules/core/src/lapack.cpp, line 876
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" ...

Comment: The latest release of JavaCV comes with a `IplImage.asCvMat()` method: We should use that.